# Веб отладка Android

Tags: android, отладка, localhost

Здравствуйте, требуется раздать интернет на телефон (Samsung Galaxy S5) с ноутбука (Windows 7 64bit). Приложение на телефоне обращается к серверу (http://server.ru для примера), нужно переадресовать все запросы на локальный виртуальный веб сервер (Denwer или OpenServer) (127.0.0.1 server.ru). Подскажите как это грамотней реализовать.

Comment: Запустите на ноутбуке DNS сервер, настройте его на выдачу IP адреса вашего ноутбука вместо реального для нужных вам доменов, пропишите использование этого dns сервера на телефоне.

Comment: Установил некий unbound (dns сервер), не могу понять как задать ip для домена

Comment: судя по документации добавить в конфиг что то вроде `local-data: "server.ru A 192.168.1.10"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу порекомендовать использовать программу fiddler на ноутбуке. Это невероятно полезная штука в веб-разработке и, в том числе, отлично подойдет для решения вашей задачи. Программа легкая, простая в использовании и бесплатна в полнофункциональной версии.

### Кратко

Установим программу fiddler на ноуте. После запуска она создает на компьютере proxy-сервер, через который начинают идти все запросы (разумеется, пока только все запросы самого компьютера). *Кроме вашей задачи программу можно использовать в отладочных целях при веб-разработке. Здесь есть такие удобные инструменты как повтор запросов или подмена ответа и фильтрация и многое другое.* Ставим в настройках галочку, чтобы прокси работал и на внешнем ip-адресе, после чего остается только в настройках wi-fi-подключения на устройстве произвести настройку прокси на наш комп (заполнить два поля). Теперь все запросы идут через комп, с учетом его DNS. Т.е. на телефоне будут работать все правила hosts с ноута.

### Подробнее

**Установить**

Идем на [официальный сайт](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), жмякаем "Free download", указываем email, снимаем галку с "подписаться", ставим галку на "согласен с условиями...", скачиваем. Установка не требует пояснений. После установки если появятся диалоговые окна - тыкаем "нет" (он там вроде что-то типа toolbar для IE свой предлагает).

**Настройка fiddler**

Запускаем программу. Сразу после запуска начинает работать и вы видите появляющиеся в списке запросы. Но нам это неинтересно и мы идем в настройки:

`Tools -> Telerik Fiddler Options -> Connections`

Здесь мы видим на каком порту работает прокси (по-умолчанию 8888), это нам пригодится на телефоне. Ниже выставляем галку `Allow remote computers to connect`, нажимаем OK, после чего программа сообщает, что настройки вступят в силу после перезапуска. Закрываем прогу и открываем снова. Все, прокси готов к работе.

[image: настройки fiddler для работы прокси на внешних ip-адресах]

**Настройка прокси на телефоне**

Идем на аппарате в настройки Wi-Fi-подключения. Не настройки Wi-Fi в целом, а настройки именно текущей подключенной сети. Там находим что-то вроде "расширенные настройки", в которых должны быть настройки прокси. Может быть они у вас не скрыты в "расширенных" и показаны сразу. В поле "**Имя хоста прокси-сервера**" или "Адрес прокси" или что-то подобное, нужно вписать ip-адрес нашего ноута в нашей подсети. В поле "**Порт**" нужно вписать тот порт, который мы видели в настройках fiddler (по-умолчанию - **8888**).

Вот так выглядят настройки у меня:

[image: настройки proxy на телефоне android]

**Готово**

Теперь все запросы в интернет с телефона идут через ваш прокси-сервер на ноуте. Все правила, прописанные в hosts на компьютере учитываются и телефон будет открывать ваш локальный сайт. Причем, вы будете видеть каждый запрос с телефона в fiddlere. Помимо настроек в hosts можно изменять DNS записи аналогичным образом в самом fiddler'e. Для этого можно зайти в раздел `Tools -> HOSTS...` и там прописывать правила. Они перестанут действовать, разумеется, при выключении программы, в отличие от правил, добавленных в файл hosts.

Когда захочется вернуть телефон на нормальный интернет, нужно отключить прокси в настройках wi-fi на телефоне. Выключение программы на ноуте без отключения прокси на телефоне приведет к потере связи на девайсе.

**Fiddler & HTTPS**

Если не ошибаюсь, по-умолчанию fiddler не обрабатывает https-запросы, а потому не мешает работе https но и не позволяет дебажить SSL-трафик. При желании, можно включить `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` в настройках, но после этого придется регулярно вносить в список "исключения", потому что массово начнут валиться разнообразные хорошо-защищенные запросы, с которыми fiddler не справился и постоянно отвечать "да да, я все понимаю" на устрашающие предупреждения хрома о "недоверенном сертификате". Но, несмотря на некоторые неудобства, можно снифать и свой SSL-трафик, если таковая возможность потребуется.

Comment: Для https достаточно установить в системе сертификат 192.168.1.3:8888/FiddlerRoot.cer (можно открыть в браузере http://192.168.1.3:8888 там будет на него ссылка) и никто ругаться больше не будет. Это можно сделать как на десктопе, так и на телефоне, все будет работать...

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо за информацию! Это именно то, чего мне так не хватало)