# Шифрование и дешифрование траффика android

Tags: java, android, https

Быть может кто-то уже сталкивался с этой задачей. Хочу посмотреть какой траффик идёт с устройства в сеть. А если это HTTPS траффик то расшифровать и посмотреть что там находиться. Знаю как-то можно сделать при помощи [VpnService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) но внятных примеров или OpenSource проектов не нашёл. Подскажите как это можно сделать, а если есть возможность поделитесь кодом.

Comment: Fiddler может помочь. тут посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554912 и комментарий к ответу по поводу https.

Comment: Я знаю про фиддлер но я хочу именно приложение.